# BizTalk 2016 DB2 adapter issues : Couldn't parse object name from polling statement DB2 adapter

Tags: db2, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am using DB2 receive location in BizTalk 2016 configured with select query in SQL Command field. When I try to enable the receive location, I am getting the below error message.

> The adapter "DB2" raised an error message. Details "There was an error in the Receive location with URI: DB2://XXXX:XX/XX/XXX. Internal message: Couldn't parse object name from polling statement".

I came to know that problem is with CASE statement inside query statement. When I remove CASE statement, it is working as expected. But the same query including CASE statement is working in BTS 2013 R2.

I tried installing latest cumulative updates for both BizTalk and HIS i.e., BizTalk 2016 CU7 and HIS 2016 CU3 and still the issue is not resolved. Can any one suggest the resolution or fix available for this?

Comment: Consider engaging the paid support channel of Microsoft, if you cannot use any built-in diagnostic capabilities supplied by BizTalk, to address this issue.

Comment: Is the case statement in SQL in the receive location or in a stored procedure that you are calling?

Comment: I am not using Stored Procedure. Using CASE statement inside select query and it  is not working. I tried using IIF function as an alternative for CASE. Even that is also not working.

Comment: Then I suggest you try using a stored procedure and configure the port to use that.  Also could you show us what your SQL statement looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Move your query to a stored procedure, and have the adapter poll that.